# trimming a substring in sql server column

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I have data in a text column that looks like `xxxxx.x.xx`
I need to get the string into a view with a format of `xxxxx.x` (removing the trailing `.xx`).

I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

I think I would need to get the length from the start to the 2nd "." and then Left that length.

I also wonder, can this be done as a column expression or would it need a function?

Here is another twist. How would I handle the same issue if the char length is variable such as `xxxxxx.xx.x` and `xxxxx.x.x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT 
    REVERSE(
        SUBSTRING(
            REVERSE(@word),
            CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@word))+1,
            LEN(REVERSE(@word))
                 )
            )
FROM yourTable
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23451)

This solution is generic, so it would work also for the case in which you have `xx.xxxx.xx.xxx` or any other number of letters sepparated by dots.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` would be helpful in such a situation

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the expression:

```
left(@s, charindex('.', @s, charindex('.', @s) + 1) - 1)
```

(where @s is your varchar value)

Online demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23448

Comment: - I added another detail to my post.

Comment: @Ryan that would still work. And by the way, for such a simple problem you should be able to add all details from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'xxxxx.x.xx' as original
,Replace( 'xxxxx.x.xx',Right('xxxxx.x.xx',3),'') as new
```